# Relationship between the Gamma and Beta distributions

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, density-function, gamma-distribution

I was looking at a proof of the following fact

Let $X \sim \mbox{Gamma}(\alpha, 1)$ and $Y \sim \mbox{Gamma}(\beta, 1)$ where the paramaterization is such that $\alpha$ is the shape parameter. Then
$$
\frac{X}{X + Y} \sim \mbox{Beta}(\alpha, \beta).
$$

found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190670/how-exactly-are-the-beta-and-gamma-distributions-related) in the second answer.

In the link I gave, when the author of the answer writes "To prove this, write the joint pdf $f_{X, Y} (x, y) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\beta)} x^{\alpha - 1} y^{\beta - 1} e^{-(x + y)}$ ", does this mean $X$ and $Y$ are to be considered independent?

Also the kind reader that may wish to give their proof of the above fact is very welcome to do so.

EDIT: when I copied pasted the linked answer I did not notice that the Lemma I would like to prove is stated a bit differently:

If $Z \sim Gamma(\alpha, \theta)$ and $W \sim Gamma(\beta, \theta)$, then $A = Z / (W+Z) \sim Beta(\alpha, \beta)$.

Comment: I am sure you can find a proof on the internet, this is pretty standard.

Comment: @JohnK ok I will look for one better and link it if I find it.

Comment: Here is one link. http://www.randomservices.org/random/special/Beta.html . Scroll down and open up the proof of 25.

Comment: Yes, you will need independence